# Formatting geom_label dates

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

Is there a way to format the dates printed by `geom_label` in `ggplot2` beyond their raw value? In the example below the dates are printed as "1910-01-01". However, say I wanted to just print the month and day and also have the month as a text value. Anyone have any ideas how I'd go about doing that?

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x=1:5,
  y=runif(5,10,40),
  Date=seq(as.Date("1910/1/1"), as.Date("1914/1/1"), "years"))


ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label(aes(label=Date))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant `geom_text` not `geom_label`.

You can use `format` to extract what you want (see `format.POSIXct` for full list)

```
 ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
     geom_point() +
     geom_text(aes(label=format(Date, format = "%b %d")))
```

[image]

Comment: No I did mean `geom_label`. And I actually was using the `ggrepel` library so the actual geom I was using was `geom_label_repel`. Still the answer works beautifully.

Comment: @boshek if you're using a different package, make sure you state that in the question. Otherwise there's no way anyone could know...

Comment: `geom_label` is part of the `ggplot2` package. I merely provided extra information `ggrepel` for interest sake. In fact I kept the question parsimonious so that I wouldn't have to add an additional library.

Comment: @boshek ah - i may not have an updated enough version (I don't have geom_label as a function)

Comment: it is great. you should try it.